# Typescript fully typed function that strips null values from object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create a function that removes any null values from an object in a fully typed way.

I have an attempt [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANseAeAKgPigXigG8AoKKAbQGkoBLAOygGsIQB7AMykwF0AuKAKIAPAMbJEAEwhYq3ADRQ6KZNmIBfYsXaI6I4DVYN4wAE40wAOWUAFAIYnbAWww4AFKwBGAK36YAlPx2Jvq2yOhwSKgu2LgkZCKGxlAmCCjAgfYhYRFp0bgEhBpkAPLeEHoAdBB0pjQI7t5+FeysJgK2IgAWrq7kjAoAbtx++LGkZLScrgNQAIR4BErIyCNxE2QpkcB93PhQA+NkRVBqfuMpwIgmDJtp6prECXRJwAjAe2tk7DTGAPp0Tgg-AARK9jMC5IcoMhbH8AY4gVBgS1WBCoQlHGBbHQQPwlshIRpHol3ps9sYzJYbPYnPBXGDgGdiAB6ZkQISQPTJBBQYCsKAeIEs5lEKDCr40ExwwEghlo1lkGHShEglHA9bitRAA)

```js
type Results<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Exclude<T[K], null>
}

function stripNullParams<T>(obj: T): Partial<Results<T>> {
  const result: Partial<Results<T>> = {}
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    if (v !== null) {
      // this says: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Partial<Results<T>>'.
      // No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Partial<Results<T>>'
      result[k] = v
      
    }
  })
  return result
}


const test = {
    fist_name: "test",
    last_name: "foo",
    company: null,
}

const res = stripNullParams(test)
```

But it doesn't seem to be working as expected. Is it possible to achieve this in Typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the key before using it. Object.entries() intentionally returns an ambiguous key type instead of `keyof T` because typescript does not guarantee that there are not *extra* properties on the object besides those specified in `T`

```
function stripNullParams<T>(obj: T): Partial<Results<T>> {
  const result: Partial<Results<T>> = {}
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    if (v !== null) {
      result[k as (keyof T)] = v
    }
  })
  return result
}
```